# How to sort multidimensional array in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sorting, for-loop

After many attempts to use sort without success, here my actual code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#define N   5


    int a[N] = { 3, 6, 2, 4, 1 }; 
    int b[N] = { 6, 3, 1, 2, 9 };
    int c[N][3];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        c[i][0] = a[i]; c[i][1] = b[i]; c[i][2] = i;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d,%d, %d\n", c[i][0], c[i][1], c[i][2] );
```

Actual output is:

```
3,6,0
6,3,1
2,1,2
4,2,3
1,9,4
```

and I need to sort with first key , outputtexpected should be like this:

```
1,9,4
2,1,2
3,6,0
4,2,3
6,3,1
```

I tried some desperate `sort(c, c + N);`.

Comment: Show us exactly how you tried to sort the array, and explain why you are not seeing the expected results.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that sorts. There is your problem.

Comment: write compare function for `qsort` then use `qsort` in C.

Comment: i tried sort(c, c + N); im gona edit my question

Comment: @BLUEPIXY any example ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use qsort version

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#define N   5

using namespace std;

int cmp(const void  *a, const void *b){
    int *x = (int*)a;
    int *y = (int*)b;
    return (*x > *y) - (*x < *y);
}

int main(){
    int a[N] = { 3, 6, 2, 4, 1 }; 
    int b[N] = { 6, 3, 1, 2, 9 };
    int c[N][3];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        c[i][0] = a[i]; c[i][1] = b[i]; c[i][2] = i;
    }
    qsort(c, N, sizeof(*c), cmp);
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d,%d, %d\n", c[i][0], c[i][1], c[i][2] ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

c-array is not assignable, and so doesn't satisfy `std::sort` requirements.

As suggested, in C++11, you may use `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<int, 3> c[5] = {
    {3, 6, 0},
    {6, 3, 1},
    {2, 1, 2},
    {4, 2, 3},
    {1, 9, 4}
};
std::sort(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/SCRw0U)

Comment: You could use `std::vector`, or create your own class array.

Comment: @user4406273 Or use `std::tr1::array` or `boost::array`.